# <option> is having each option its own drop down

Tags: php, html

so my script gets data from sql then puts it in option I want them all in one drop down tab but its giving each category its own tab idk how to fix it any ideas or suggestions

```
          <form action="" method="post">
            <select name="work_place">
            <option value="<?php echo $category;?>"><?php echo $category;?>
            </option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="go" />
        </form>
```

[image]

Comment: Can You Please update the Question with the array list(sql) that you are mapping ?

Comment: I suppose there's a loop somewhere around this code? Place your form & select outside of the loop, just loop the `<option>`s

Comment: Your code should contain a loop, but the code you shown has no loop at all. Please post more of your code so you can get proper answer.

Comment: There is definitely a `for` loop above the `form` element. You need to put that loop within the `select` element.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Is it no longer needed because one of the answer resolved your issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
<select name="products">
    <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
        <?php
        // A sample product array
        $products = array("Mobile", "Laptop", "Tablet", "Camera");
        
        // Iterating through the product array
        foreach($products as $item){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo strtolower($item); ?>"><?php echo $item; ?></option>
     <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Try this as reference and for each loop

you must be using for each or for loop above the form tag.. 
**You just have to loop the `<option>` Tag**

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and image, the problem is you warped your `<select>` inside your `loop` its wrong way to do it.

the `loop` should generate only `<option>` so try like below,

```
foreach ($categories as $cat_name) { 
   echo "<option value='$cat_name'>$cat_name</option>";
}
```

FYI: Just add only `<option>` inside your `loop` and rest outside your loop.